# manage TO-DO list in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, to-do

Is there a way a do it in Notepad++, as in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any plugins for Notepad++ for this, for a time I did something similar to this: <strike>[Geakz](http://www.geakz.com/2008/08/06/managing-to-do-lists-with-notepad/)</strike> (Site down 2016-07-29) But now I use [Stickies](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/)

Comment: i guess no TODO's for me on notepad

stickies does seem nice
thank you :)

Comment: downvoted - this is not the answer, just workaround

Answer (score 8):

if you have inline todos in your code like

```
// TODO: remember to fix this.
```

then you can use this plugin for notepad++ http://code.google.com/p/npp-task-list/.

Comment: Eventually, that's how i do it. thank you sir!

Comment: Seems dead. Plugin no longer installs on current NPP. And [the "npp-task-list" project seems to have been abandoned early 2015](https://code.google.com/archive/p/npp-task-list/issues/21). Pity.

Answer (score 1):

NPP plugin for task list is sounding and kicking (aka alive!) https://github.com/Megabyteceer/npp-task-list but with the poor help/documentation, scattered online:

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17381/npp-task-list-plugin/6 - describes config file & keywords

> look for the npp_task_list.cfg file into: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config\ for 32 bit notepad++ or C:\Program
> Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config\ for 64 bit notepad++ versions.
>
> keywords= TODO: BUG: FIX: REFACTOR: DONE: INFO:

https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/27/windows/task-list-notepad-todo-task-list-plugin.html - general info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is what you were looking for : `Task list`

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/31/task-list

Comment: You should add a bit more to your answer on why this is what OP is looking for. Quote a list of features, maybe include a screenshot, and so on.