# Keywords in plugin Task List for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In relation with [manage TO-DO list in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/143640/manage-to-do-list-in-notepad/1753113#1753113) I have an unexplained behaviour with the installed Notepad++ plugin **Task List**.

I have added the file `npp_task_list.cfg` to the right folder. I see also that it is working for "TODO:" (see [Todo Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFop5.png)).

I see also if I modify the todo keyword, it disappears from the list. [Todo does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td1cS.png)

Why are the other keywords not working? The only idea I would have is that I am using the 64bit version, but I am lost, what could be wrong? I really would like to use other keywords that appear in the task list to the right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: This is a QA site, not a forum. Each question gets its own post so that it can get it's own answers, even if it is related to or a follow up to an existing answer. This should be clear from the names of the fields. Your previous message was deleted because it was a question entered into an Answer field. I recommend visiting the Help section to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Edit 2022-11-17:**

Notepad++ Plugins Admin currently (at time of writing) only installs *Task List Version 2.4* but **Task List Version 2.5** is out there and fixes the issue you described. Therefore, you have to install the latest version manually.

Use the links below for this update.

- [Notepad++ Plugin List - 64 bit](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/nppPluginList/blob/master/doc/plugin_list_x64.md) - (scroll down or click here for ZIP file: [Task List     2.5 - 64 bit](https://github.com/Megabyteceer/npp-task-list/releases/download/v2.5.0/NppTaskList_v2.5.0_x64.zip)) **OR**
- https://github.com/Megabyteceer/npp-task-list/releases/tag/v2.5.0

To get more keywords e.g. `TEAM:` you have to change the `npp_task_list.cfg` file. To do this, start your text editor with extended rights as administrator.

BTW - searching for the editor (e.g. Notepad++) in the Start menu and then typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> lets you run the program as an administrator.

```
version=
1

keywords=
TODO:
BUG:
FIX:
REFACTOR:
DONE:
INFO:
TEAM:
```

[image]

[image]

---

I first have only managed the following solution as a workaround under Windows10 x64 using Notepad++ v8.4.7 (64-bit). Please note this was thought for **Task List Version 2.4** only.

- Created `config` folder under `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\NppTaskList`
- inserted a `$` sign in front of each keyword

Comment: Ohh, this is getting closer. I tried as you mentioned, and it works for the keywords in there, but I cannot add new ones. 
Can you add $TEST: for example? Does that work for you?

Update: never mind, as usual, a restart of Notepad++ fixes it.

Thanks a lot and high five!

Comment: @Nico Vadøy - see my edit ...

Comment: @Nico Vadøy - you're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.